# Divider of empty listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

In iPhone app, the empty tableview has the separators.

But I created a ListView in Android app and the empty ListView can't show the dividers.

So the ListView is only white board.

How to fill the dividers into ListView of Android as iPhone app?

Comment: `ListView of Android app looks ugly` ... it's a matter of taste ... still, android's listview/ListFragment can show text with some information if there is no elements

Comment: If a `ListView` is empty in Android it is supposed to display a text, see `setEmptyText()` in the `ListFragment`. Look at Google Apps, I think you will not find one instance of a `ListView` with dividers when no elements are present.

Comment: And there is always the logical question: Why have a divider if there is nothing to divide?

Comment: And then there is the next logical question: How is the `ListView` supposed to know where to place the dividers if there are no elements?  Just placing them in some default order would not be very nice.

Comment: Just because iOS does it this way doesn't mean that it is the best or most beautiful way. It's just one way of doing things. Android is simply different.

Answer (score 1):

Each platform has it's own specifications and behavior.. it's highly discouraged to copy from other plateforms

Have a look at this article [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

**Update**

this may be a helpful link if you don't have experience working with [ListViews](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: you can always use `setEmptyView()` for `ListViews`.. it'll help you improve your empty list

Answer (score 0):

I agree, 
Each platform has its own looks and behavior.

If it looks too white plain or very "simple" as you mentioned:

Try to use setEmptyView to show some notice or text which will let users that it's a listview and it's now empty.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)